# Timezone discrepancy between apache logs on two identical servers

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, logs, date, timezone

I have cloned a server to sit behind a load balancer with the original. When looking through the apache access logs, the cloned server is in the wrong timezone. This seems like an easy thing to fix but I can't find out how to adjust this setting.

How do you change the timezone reported in access logs?

Answer (score 2):

Centos 6:

1) Open `/etc/sysconfig/clock`

2) Modify ZONE to your desired, like:

```
ZONE=Europe/Prague
```

3) Run following command to make it effective:

```
tzdata-update
```

**EDIT:**

Despite this is the official RH advised method, the tzdata-update doesn't seem to work in RHEL 6.9. In that case, change link /etc/localtime to the desired timezone, which can be found in the /usr/share/zoneinfo/ directory. See the example:

```
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Oslo /etc/localtime
```

---

Centos 7:

There is special command for setting timezone:

```
timedatectl set-timezone Europe/Prague
```

---

Regarding modification of logs retrospectively, I'm not sure if there's such tool. You'd have to prepare some script, which would grep dates from one of logs, let it convert with correct ofset and replace with sed in the log.

Comment: Using CentOS 6.9. I tried your first solution and it didn't work using timezone `America/Phoenix` (was originally `America/Chicago`). The command `date` returns the original timezone and logs still show -0600. Also `tzdata-update` returned no error (not that I'm aware it would)

Comment: @usernotfound You're correct, despite mentioned procedure is officially adviced by RH (https://access.redhat.com/solutions/7089). The only working method is link /etc/localtime. I'm going to modify the answer accordingly.